# Android studio splash screen loops my activity - threading

Tags: android, multithreading

first of all I´m new to Android. I have found a piece of code to make splash on app startup. When I integrated with my project I get infinitive loop on my login/second activity. I´m guessing I do something wrong with the threading.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class WelcomeSplashLogo extends Activity{

public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}

Thread splashTread;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_splash_logo);
    StartAnimations();


}

private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 3500) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, WelcomeSplashLogo.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish();

                Intent intentGoToHomeActivity = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, LoginActivity.class);
                WelcomeSplashLogo.this.startActivity(intentGoToHomeActivity);
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}
```

}

Comment: why you are using loop...you can directly call sleep(3500)...

Comment: I do inside the thread, but somehow on finally my new intent is regenerated like it would be in a loop

Comment: that loop is the issue...remove it..and use sleep(3500)

Comment: No it is not that, I have changed it just in case, but still every 3,5s I have new login intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just because of the below lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, WelcomeSplashLogo.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish();
```

You are calling Same Activity i.e. WelcomeSplashLogo.class.

Comment: +1. You could also consider adding the solution too. That being said, you have already pointed the OP in the right direction and he / she _should_ put some effort figuring that one out. ;-)

Comment: @IceMAN I think thats enough, because by removing that lines is itself the Solution. No more addition required. By the way Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `Handler` to queue and run your task after the specified amount of time elapses and go to next screen...

```
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;    
runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);  // delay time...
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. Unfortunately I cannot find postDelayed method of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think it is a great idea to make the user wait for 3.5 seconds if you can show your main app sooner.

I made some comments to your code:

```
splashTread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int waited = 0;
            // Splash screen pause time
            while (waited < 3500) {    // why loop? sleep(3500) would do it, too.
                sleep(100);
                waited += 100;
            }
            /*
            Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, WelcomeSplashLogo.class);  // You call your SplashLogo Activity again. 
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish();   // this is called in finally block already, therefore it is not needed here
            */
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        } finally {
            WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish();

            Intent intentGoToHomeActivity = new Intent(WelcomeSplashLogo.this, LoginActivity.class);
            WelcomeSplashLogo.this.startActivity(intentGoToHomeActivity);
        }

    }
};
splashTread.start();
```

Comment: I got rid of the loop, the redundant call of WelcomeSplashLogo.this.finish() and SplashLogo activity, also as user5716019 suggested. Thank you for help.